# Apply aggregate functions on array fields in Postgres?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Is it possible to apply aggregates (like avg(), stddev()) on all the values in an integer[] field (or other arrays of numbers)?

```
CREATE TABLE widget
(
  measurement integer[]
);

insert into widget (measurement) values ( '{1, 2, 3}');

select avg(measurement::integer[]) from widget;

ERROR:  function avg(integer[]) does not exist
LINE 4: select avg(measurement::integer[]) from widget;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function avg(integer[]) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 71
```

I can work around by splitting the array into multiple rows like

```
select avg(m)::float from (select unnest(measurement) m from widget) q;
```

but it's less elegant.

Thank you.

Comment: You can define a custom aggregate, that will work with an array. Or create a simple function that will convert an array to a single aggregated value and aggregate on top of this function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can create simple function like this:

```
create function array_avg(_data anyarray)
returns numeric
as
$$
    select avg(a)
    from unnest(_data) as a
$$ language sql;
```

and query it like this

```
select avg(array_avg(measurement))
from widget;
```

or you can simply do

```
select avg((select avg(a) from unnest(measurement) as a))
from widget;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/73ca8/4)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to know how to do this while keeping other attributes, without grouping, lateral joins provide a simple solution:

```
select Point, High, Low, Average
    from GridPoint G
    join lateral (
        select Max(V) High, Min(V) Low, Avg(V) Average
            from Unnest(G.Values) V
    ) _ on true
```