# Aggregate Avg() over array fields in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Before this question gets flagged and closed, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962605/apply-aggregate-functions-on-array-fields-in-postgres) question already, yet it does not quite answer my problem.

I would like to calculate the element-wise average over the arrays in the field per row, and keep the dimensionsionality

```sql
create table if not exists my_arrays (array_field float[]);

insert into my_arrays values ('{1,2,3}');
insert into my_arrays values ('{3,2,1}');
insert into my_arrays values ('{3,2,1}');
insert into my_arrays values ('{1,2,3}');

select avg(array_field) as x from my_arrays;
```

Which should output:

```
    x
---------
{2, 2, 2}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The error is get is that no avg(float[]) exists ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unnest...with ordinality` to break them apart while labeling their positions, then group by position, then reassemble with array_agg.

```
select array_agg(avg order by ordinality) from (
    select ordinality, avg(unnest) from my_arrays, unnest(array_field) with ordinality group by ordinality
) foo;
```

You need to make sure it deals with NULLs and missing values in a way you find suitable.

If you will be doing this a lot, it might make sense to define your own aggregate that operates over `float[]`.