# Take average from a delimited string in a single expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-superset

I have a data table in Postgres containing a column `age` that contains people ages. Unfortunately this data is dirty, so it includes string entries, which might represent ranges, featuring all of these formats:

```
21
25-30
30-35 years
```

Using [Apache Superset](https://superset.apache.org/) I am making a chart from this data. I can apply functions on this column, so for example I am using this expression to get the lower bound of ranges `split_part(split_part("age",' ',1),'-', 1)::int`.

However, the lower bound is not really representative of the data. I'd like when I have a range to get the average. I've tried:

```
avg(unnest(string_to_array(split_part("age",' ',1),'-')::int[]))
```

But I get:

```
aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls
LINE 1: SELECT avg(unnest(string_to_array(split_part("ageValue",' ',...
               ^
HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

This is available as a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e804d/3).

I've seen [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18962605) of how this can be done with a select or function, but I cannot use any of these in the Superset X-axis query. Can it be done with expressions only and if so - how?

Comment: It will be a lot easier to write a query if you extract the ages to two separate columns. For fixed ages you can put the same number in both columns. SQL is a query language, not a text processing language.

Comment: You can use regular expressions to extract the age parts and ignore the rest of the string. `^\d+` is enough to extract the starting age. `^(?:\d+-)\d+` should only capture the end date. Once you have the range columns you could use a tally table to calculate all ages between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, the silver bullet would be to clean up your data.

For a quick fix with a single expression:

```sql
SELECT *, CASE
           WHEN age ~ ' ' THEN (split_part(age, '-', 1)::float8 + split_part(split_part(age, ' ', 1), '-', 2)::float8) / 2
           WHEN age ~ '-' THEN (split_part(age, '-', 1)::float8 + split_part(           age         , '-', 2)::float8) / 2
           ELSE age::float8
          END AS avg_age
FROM   data;
```

With aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id, age, avg(age_bound) AS avg_age
FROM  (
   SELECT *, string_to_table(split_part(age, ' ', 1), '-')::float8 AS age_bound
   FROM   data
   ) sub
GROUP  BY id, age
ORDER  BY id;  -- optional
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PtPeB4dC)

[`string_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.35.1.1.1) was added with Postgres 14.

Comment: In the question I explicitly said I've seen solutions with select, but these cannot be used

Comment: @mapto: Right, I missed that. Added a single-expression solution. (You *always* need a `SELECT`, though.)

Comment: Genious! :P I was trying to use the AVG function, never thought of actually averaging it myself.

Comment: @mapto: You already accepted, but there was a bug. Note the update.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it and I tried to correct your answer, but StackOverflow did not allow me to do it, due to edit queue being full. Notice that your first two cases could be merged (what you did before), as it doesn't matter if there is ' ' or not, in either case you can take `split_part(age, ' ', 1)`. Your mistake previously was that you were checking for ' ', whereas you should've been checking for '-' only. Anyway, thanks!